# Не запекается текстура в Blender

Tags: blender

Пытаюсь запечь текстуру в блендер, но она не запекается.
Вот так выглядит исходная модель:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так получается после запекания:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Развёртка нормальная, пару часов назад точно так же запекал текстуру процессора, там всё преркасно получилось, но не здесь.
Еще пару скринов для понимания:

Настройки запекания: (крутил их в разной коомбинации, не помогло)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Развёртка объекта, на который должна запечься текстура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Один из двух материалов на исходном объекте: (Второй реализован точно так же, только Base Color светлее)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема?